# Android Studio: Textview in Bluetooth Chat sample

Tags: android, android-layout, bluetooth, nullpointerexception, android-bluetooth

I am using `Bluetooth` Chat sample to receive Sensor Data from my Arduino on my Android Device. I'm trying to display the incoming message to a `TextView`. Here's my code for the `Bluetooth` Chat `Fragment` class

```
package com.example.android.bluetoothchat;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android.common.logger.Log;

/**
 * This fragment controls Bluetooth to communicate with other devices.
 */
public class BluetoothChatFragment extends Fragment {


private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatFragment";

// Intent request codes
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;

// Layout Views
private ListView mConversationView;
private EditText mOutEditText;
private Button mSendButton;
private TextView display;

/**
 * Name of the connected device
 */
private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;

/**
 * Array adapter for the conversation thread
 */
private ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter;

/**
 * String buffer for outgoing messages
 */
private StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;

/**
 * Local Bluetooth adapter
 */
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;

/**
 * Member object for the chat services
 */
private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    // Get local Bluetooth adapter
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        activity.finish();
    }
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
    // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        // Otherwise, setup the chat session
    } else if (mChatService == null) {
        setupChat();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mChatService != null) {
        mChatService.stop();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
    // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
    // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
    if (mChatService != null) {
        // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
        if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE) {
            // Start the Bluetooth chat services
            mChatService.start();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bluetooth_chat, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mConversationView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.in);
    mOutEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
    mSendButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    display = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kotak);
}

/**
 * Set up the UI and background operations for chat.
 */
private void setupChat() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");

    // Initialize the array adapter for the conversation thread
    mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.message);

    mConversationView.setAdapter(mConversationArrayAdapter);

    // Initialize the compose field with a listener for the return key
    mOutEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mWriteListener);

    // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
            View view = getView();
            if (null != view) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
                String message = textView.getText().toString();
                sendMessage(message);
            }
        }
    });

    // Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
    mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(getActivity(), mHandler);

    // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
    mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
}

/**
 * Makes this device discoverable for 300 seconds (5 minutes).
 */
private void ensureDiscoverable() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() !=
            BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    }
}

/**
 * Sends a message.
 *
 * @param message A string of text to send.
 */
private void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mChatService.write(send);

        // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
        mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
        mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
    }
}

/**
 * The action listener for the EditText widget, to listen for the return key
 */
private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener
        = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the message
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
        return true;
    }
};

/**
 * Updates the status on the action bar.
 *
 * @param resId a string resource ID
 */
private void setStatus(int resId) {
    FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    final ActionBar actionBar = activity.getActionBar();
    if (null == actionBar) {
        return;
    }
    actionBar.setSubtitle(resId);
}

/**
 * Updates the status on the action bar.
 *
 * @param subTitle status
 */
private void setStatus(CharSequence subTitle) {
    FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    final ActionBar actionBar = activity.getActionBar();
    if (null == actionBar) {
        return;
    }
    actionBar.setSubtitle(subTitle);
}

/**
 * The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
 */
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();

        switch (msg.what) {
            case Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to, mConnectedDeviceName));
                        mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                        break;
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        setStatus(R.string.title_connecting);
                        break;
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                        setStatus(R.string.title_not_connected);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the buffer
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);


                mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName + ":  " + readMessage);
                    display.setText(readMessage);
                break;

            case Constants.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(Constants.DEVICE_NAME);
                if (null != activity) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Connected to "
                            + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_TOAST:
                if (null != activity) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, msg.getData().getString(Constants.TOAST),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                connectDevice(data, true);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                connectDevice(data, false);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
                setupChat();
            } else {
                // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occurred
                Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
    }
}

/**
 * Establish connection with other device
 *
 * @param data   An {@link Intent} with {@link DeviceListActivity#EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS} extra.
 * @param secure Socket Security type - Secure (true) , Insecure (false)
 */
private void connectDevice(Intent data, boolean secure) {
    // Get the device MAC address
    String address = data.getExtras()
            .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    // Get the BluetoothDevice object
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    // Attempt to connect to the device
    mChatService.connect(device, secure);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.bluetooth_chat, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.secure_connect_scan: {
            // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
            Intent serverIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeviceListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE);
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.insecure_connect_scan: {
            // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
            Intent serverIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeviceListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE);
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.discoverable: {
            // Ensure this device is discoverable by others
            ensureDiscoverable();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}}
```

Problem is when I launched the application in my android, the app crashed after receiving `bluetooth` data. The report bug I get from the application is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference 
 at
com.example.android.bluetoothchat.BluetoothChatFragment$3.handleMessage(BluetoothChatFragment.java:315) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5442) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.android.internal.os.Zygotelnit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygotelnit.java:738) 
 at com.android.internal.os.Zygotelnit.main(Zygotelnit.java:628)
```

Can anybody help me for this problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: share your layout file of **fragment_bluetooth_chat**

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your **`TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);`** from your **`mSendButton.setOnClickListener`** and intilize it  it into your **`onViewCreated`** like below code

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mConversationView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.in);
    mOutEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
    mSendButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    display = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.kotak);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, still crashed, the report bug is still the same :(

Comment: @GlenPutranto SHARE YOUR LAYOUT OF **`fragment_bluetooth_chat`**